# ¿ Cómo obtener los datos de cada columna en una matriz json?

Tags: javascript, php, json, html-tabla

este es mi código el cual al ejecutar me trae solo los primeros dos valores del json los demás datos no me lo reconoce y es que no se como solucionarlo lo estoy intentando pero no lo logro

```html
<!--este es el json del cual debo extraer los valores y pasarlos a una tabla html  -->
    <?php
                                            
                                            $jsonobj = '{  "codigo" : " 00 "  ,
                                                "descripcion" : " Consulta exitosa "  ,
                                                "movimientos" : [
                                                    {
                                                        "comercio_desc" : " ATIPICO RIVERA "  ,
                                                        "fch_com" : " 05/01/21 "  ,
                                                        "importe" : " 10000 "  ,
                                                        "mov_tp" : " D "  ,
                                                        "referencia_nro" : " 100530994259 "  ,
                                                        "tarjeta" : " 6274311750000090 "
                                                    }
                                                ]}';
                                                $decodedJson = json_decode($jsonobj, true);
                                                
                                                ?>

//esta es la tabla el cual deberia recibir los valores del json
<table id="tblUsuarios" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-td-valign-middle" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">Codigo</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">descripcion</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">comercio_desc</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">fch_com</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">importe</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">mov_tp</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">referencia_nro</th>
                                                <th class="hidden-sm text-center">tarjeta</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        
                                         
                                            <tr>

                                                
                                                <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center">   <?php echo $decodedJson["codigo"] ; ?> </td>
                                                <td class="text-nowrap text-inverse text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["descripcion"] ; ?></td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["comercio_desc"] ; ?> </td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["fch_com"] ; ?> </td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["importe"]; ?> </td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["mov_tp"]; ?></td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"> <?php echo $decodedJson["referencia_nro"]; ?></td>
                                                <td class="f-w-600 text-muted text-center"><?php echo $decodedJson["tarjeta"]; ?> </td>
                                            
                                                </td>
                                                
                                            </tr>
        
                                            </tbody>
                                    </table>
```

---

he logrado obtener los datos con este bucle ahora necesito filtrarlos por fecha  ,de nuevo me quede corto con json ¿alguien podría darme una mano por favor?

```
for ($i=0; $i <count($decodedJson["movimientos"]); $i++) { 

?>
```

//Aqui muestras los registros de tu tabla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te falta incluir el item "movimientos"

```
$decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["comercio_desc"];

$decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["fch_com"];

$decodedJson["movimientos"][0]["importe"];
```

Comment: ahora probe agregarle $ decodedJson ["movimientos"] [0] ["fch_com"]; y funciono Gracias Jhonmer Araujo

Comment: @ALDO56, si te sirvió la respuesta, no olvides marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Gracias Jhonmer Araujo he logrado obtener los datos del json  ahora necesito filtrarlos por fecha